# BigQuery refusing to insert few records while streaming

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming, schema

I have been constantly trying to stream data to BigQuery using python google-cloud package `from google.cloud import bigquery`.

What I have observed is that it is refusing to insert few rows saying that

```
[{u'debugInfo': u'', u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'no such field.', u'location': u'user.new_user'}]}]
```

But, I could see that column in the schema `table.schema`

```
[(u'USER', u'record', u'NULLABLE', None, (SchemaField(u'new_user', u'string', u'NULLABLE', None, ())))]
```

Is this because, i am trying to stream & update at a more rate than mentioned in BigQuery docs ?

I tried to run the same thing on terminal and this worked with no errors. This is happening when I try to stream at a more higher rate.

For now, I am using as

```
self.bigquery_client.create_rows_json(table, batched_event,retry=bigquery.DEFAULT_RETRY.with_deadline(10),skip_invalid_rows=True, ignore_unknown_values=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're modifying the schema while using streaming, the streaming system doesn't immediately pick up the schema changes.  More info:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts

Comment: Can you share better workaround regarding this ? How can we deal with such data which has constantly changing schema

Comment: If its not simply a sparse schema, one possibility is to consider a more generalized schema that doesn't require schema evolution.  BigQuery supports complex types, so it may be possible to model some things as an array of generalized key/value structs as an example.  Another strategy may just be to backoff more aggressively and retry in the face of schema mismatch responses.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. Can you provide some insight around retrying ? Can I fetch only failed records in a batch while streaming  so that I can try them again later after 10 min or so?